# How to create calculated member for a previous period date

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas

I created in my SSAS cube a calculated member to get the Previous Period, it's the following code:

```
IIF([DIM DATE].[Hierarchy Année Mois Jour].CurrentMember.level.ordinal = 0,
[Measures].[Prix Vendu],
    (ParallelPeriod([DIM DATE].[Hierarchy Année Mois Jour].[Année],
    1,
    [DIM DATE].[Hierarchy Année Mois Jour].CurrentMember),[Measures].[Prix Vendu]
    )
)
```

I have a date hierarchy (Year -> Month -> Day) and that calculation works well

When I use the cube in excel, I sometime use the date in the filter section instead of putting it on the reports to select my dates. But when I do that, the calculation isn't working well.

Anyone have tips or tutorial or good function I need to look at or use?

Thanks